Sushi V3Pool smart contract - what to put in "bytes calldata data" parameter of "swap" method? Or how to perform swap programmatically?
Hey guys thanks in advance!
I'm using Sushi.com V3 liquidity pools manually, but I like to automate everything. So I'm trying to create liquidity manager in Go, I use Geth as Golang-Eth SDK but my question is rather smart-contract related than Go-related.
First, I want to perform swap operation in V3 liquidity pool on Sushi programmatically.
I have found description of swap method here:
https://docs.sushi.com/docs/Products/V3%20AMM/Core/Contracts/V3Pool#swap
And also here, since Sushi is a "branch" of Uni:
https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v3/reference/core/interfaces/pool/IUniswapV3PoolActions#swap
Here is the signature of V3Pool "swap" method:
function swap(
    address recipient,
    bool zeroForOne,
    int256 amountSpecified,
    uint160 sqrtPriceLimitX96,
    bytes calldata data
) external override noDelegateCall returns (int256 amount0, int256 amount1);

As we can see, there are no token-addresses among swap function arguments as well as deadline parameter, I expect they should be passed in "data" parameter? But I can't find anywhere what exactly I should "pack" in data bytes array.
What I already did?

I found V3 pool smart contract here:
https://www.sushi.com/pool/8453%3A0x9efe71955931c31c1c63395df11063289332bf8b -- this one is for Base network.

Then found that contract at Base explorer:
https://basescan.org/address/0x9efe71955931c31c1c63395df11063289332bf8b#code

I copied ABI-JSON data and created json-constant BASE_ROUTER_ABI in
my project.

Then, I instantiated smart contract "interface" (not correct term,
but I can't explain better :)) using that ABI data:
parsedABI, err := abi.JSON(strings.NewReader(BASE_ROUTER_ABI))


And now, I'm trying to create transaction data something like here:
// 1 dollar
amountSpecified := new(big.Int).SetUint64(1)

// Since I pland swap USDC for USDbC, sqrtPriceX96 = 1*2^96 (for simplicity)
sqrtPriceX96 := new(big.Int).Mul(new(big.Int).SetUint64(1), new(big.Int).Exp(new(big.Int).SetUint64(2), new(big.Int).SetUint64(96), nil))

transactionData, err = parsedABI.Pack("swap", 0x12345....., true, amountSpecified, sqrtPriceX96, data /* What put here? */)

I have also tried to copy JSON-ABI and Bytecode, then compiled them with "abigen" to Go interface where all smart contract functions are reflected (wrapped?) with golang ones. But this also helped me not. I still don't know what to put in "data" ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.
I also asked ChatGPT hehe :) But unfortunatelly he can only help with solution for V2 pools, he does not know anything about V3.
I appreciate ANY help. Thank you!
PS. Somewhere on Youtube I have heard, that if I want to interact with new V3 smart contracts (Sushi, Uni - whatever) I should create my own smart contract for that, I can't do this from my local computer with my Ethereum SDK. But I'm unsure if this is really true.

It's data for the called back contract IUniswapV3SwapCallback(msg.sender).uniswapV3SwapCallback(amount0, amount1, data); For example a router or your own contract, where when called you transfer enough tokens to cover the balance check just after. Lots of Uniswap and Sushi examples here, including v3 router/universal router, Sushi route processor and more. https://github.com/0xMaka/w3py/blob/main/v3exactOutputSingle.py If have time to I will do a direct on pool v3 example, or you may be able to get from answers to previous questions on the site about flash loan callbacks.

Thank you, @Maka for trying to help, but I see my question cannot be answered correctly. The short answer is - it is not possible to interact with SushiV3Pool directly from computer, only from another smart contract. I have added an "answer" below. I'm sure I'm not the only one who tries to take the easy way out, but the truth is that there is no easy way anymore :)

As I said for example a router or your own contract, yes that is true in terms of using the callback, but you can still swap from script. You can even make complex swaps using the universal router command byte mechanic.

There is no correct answer for my question, but the best I found is:
It is not possible to interact with SushiV3Pool smart contract directly (from your computer from any SDK) because smart contract expects a callback to run after swap. While there is no any callback at your wallet (since wallet is not a contract), smart contract will fail, causing transaction to revert.
I have found this explanation here (in comments): How to trade directly with Uniswap V3 pool instead of through router?
So, "data" parameter can be arbitrary, it legally can be empty also, but you should create your own smart contract as intermediary between you backend and SushiV3Pool.
